# Firing rule in Clips not working properly

Tags: rules, rule-engine, clip, clips

I am new ti clips and is trying to write the rules for triggering a set of rule. 
the condition for rule is

Calculate the discount of products of product 1, product 2, product 3 as 10,  only if product 1 is present(mandatory). and the total quantity of products is greater than or equal to 6.

```
(deftemplate Product
   (slot productNumber)
   (slot quantity))

(defrule sum_of_quantity
   (exists (Product (productNumber 1 | 2 | 3)(quantity ?q&:(> ?q 1))))
   =>
   (bind ?totalQuantity 0)
   (do-for-all-facts ((?p Product))
                     (or (eq ?p:productNumber 1)
                         (eq ?p:productNumber 2)
                         (eq ?p:productNumber 3))
      (bind ?totalQuantity (+ ?totalQuantity ?p:quantity)))
   (if (>= ?totalQuantity 6) then
      (printout t "TotalQuantity is " ?totalQuantity "and discoun is 10" crlf)))

(deffacts input1 
   (Product (productNumber 2)(quantity 3))
   (Product (productNumber 3)(quantity 3)))
```

The facts was entered as shown and even without the mandatory product the result is computed and shown as 10.

Do suggest.

Comment: The output of this program is "TotalQuantity is 6and discoun is 10". The 6 that is displayed is the correctly computed value of ?totalQuantity. The 10 that is displayed is not a computed value; those characters are contained in the string passed to the printout command.

Comment: Yes. The discount is a constant value of 10. But product 1 is the mandatory product. So even without the product 1 the total quantity is computed for the other product. How can i make the rule to fire if only product 1 is available in facts?

Comment: Use (productNumber 1) rather than (productNumber 1 | 2 | 3) in the conditions of the rule.

Comment: @GaryRiley : Would it be okay if you could provide the LHS of the rule. when i tried with (productNumber 1)(productNumber 2|3). the rule doesnt get fired when there is a single product which is productNumber 1. The totalquantity is not calculated when there is a single product in the fact of product 1. The rule should work when 1,2,3 are present, 1,2 or 1,3 are present and also when just product 1 is present. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate Product
   (slot productNumber)
   (slot quantity))
CLIPS> 
(defrule sum_of_quantity
   (exists (Product (productNumber 1) (quantity ?q&:(> ?q 1))))
   =>
   (bind ?totalQuantity 0)
   (do-for-all-facts ((?p Product))
                     (or (eq ?p:productNumber 1)
                         (eq ?p:productNumber 2)
                         (eq ?p:productNumber 3))
      (bind ?totalQuantity (+ ?totalQuantity ?p:quantity)))
   (if (>= ?totalQuantity 6) then
      (printout t "TotalQuantity is " ?totalQuantity " and discount is 10" crlf)))
CLIPS> (assert (Product (productNumber 1) (quantity 6)))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (run)
TotalQuantity is 6 and discount is 10
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (assert (Product (productNumber 1) (quantity 3)))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (assert (Product (productNumber 2) (quantity 2)))
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> (assert (Product (productNumber 3) (quantity 4)))
<Fact-3>
CLIPS> (run)
TotalQuantity is 9 and discount is 10
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (assert (Product (productNumber 2) (quantity 2)))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (assert (Product (productNumber 3) (quantity 4)))
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> (run)
CLIPS>
```